# SQL Server Analysis Services - Datamining Error 5

Tags: ssas, olap-cube, ssas-2008

I'm getting this error when I'm trying process DataMining with NestedTable in it.

```
Error 5 Errors in the metadata manager. The 'XYZZZZZ' dimension in the 'Dim XYZ' measure group has either zero or multiple granularity attributes. 
Must have exactly one attribute. 0 0
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you post your mining structure's  code?

I think you have to create it with the MISSING_VALUE_SUBSTITUTION parameter to get rid of zero granularities. It always solves my proble when I have a times series with a gap on it